# ¿Como darle formato al json cuando viene en un arreglo secuencial?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, jsonobject, jsonarray

Tengo el siguiente problema, recupero este json de una consulta con la propiedad SubItems y dentro de esta viene n cantidad de objetos nombrados con numeros en secuencia
y necesito darle formato con un modelo pero no consigo encontrar una forma, hay que tener en cuenta que pueden ser n elementos dentro del objeto SubItems

```
SubItems\": {\"1\": {\"Name\": \"Aros de cebolla\", \"tax1\": {\"TAXID\": \"6\", \"TAXNAME\": \"IVA 12\", \"TAXRATE\": \"0.12\", \"TAXEXCLUSIVE\": \"N\", \"TAXINCLUSIVE\": \"Y\"}, \"tax2\": \"\", \"Price\": 0, \"Quantity\": 1, \"ModCodeId\": 1, \"MenuItemId\": 23116, \"ModGroupId\": 10067, \"PriceTotal\": 0, \"Quantity_inicial\": 1}, \"2\": {\"Name\": \"Coca-Cola Sabor Original 400cc\", \"tax1\": {\"TAXID\": \"6\", \"TAXNAME\": \"IVA 12\", \"TAXRATE\": \"0.12\", \"TAXEXCLUSIVE\": \"N\", \"TAXINCLUSIVE\": \"Y\"}, \"tax2\": \"\", \"Price\": 0, \"Quantity\": 1, \"ModCodeId\": 1, \"MenuItemId\": 25263, \"ModGroupId\": 10066, \"PriceTotal\": 0, \"Quantity_inicial\": 1}},
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer uso de `Newtonsoft.Json` y crear un método que le de formato a los json string:

```
   public class JsonFoo
   {
      public static string AplicarFormato(string jsonString)
      {
         dynamic json= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
         return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);
      }
   }
```

Con ese método, podrías obtener un json string con formato de la siguiente manera:

```
var jsonString = JsonFoo.AplicarFormato(objeto.SubItems);
```

Si lo escribes en un archivo json, se ve de la siguiente forma:

```
{
  "1": {
    "Name": "Aros de cebolla",
    "tax1": {
      "TAXID": "6",
      "TAXNAME": "IVA 12",
      "TAXRATE": "0.12",
      "TAXEXCLUSIVE": "N",
      "TAXINCLUSIVE": "Y"
    },
    "tax2": "",
    "Price": 0,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "ModCodeId": 1,
    "MenuItemId": 23116,
    "ModGroupId": 10067,
    "PriceTotal": 0,
    "Quantity_inicial": 1
  },
  "2": {
    "Name": "Coca-Cola Sabor Original 400cc",
    "tax1": {
      "TAXID": "6",
      "TAXNAME": "IVA 12",
      "TAXRATE": "0.12",
      "TAXEXCLUSIVE": "N",
      "TAXINCLUSIVE": "Y"
    },
    "tax2": "",
    "Price": 0,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "ModCodeId": 1,
    "MenuItemId": 25263,
    "ModGroupId": 10066,
    "PriceTotal": 0,
    "Quantity_inicial": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Ya intente realizarlo como me mecionas y no me da el resultado esperado, de hecho me arroja un error de formato cuando intenta desearilzar.
Es que como te comento esta propiedad es parte de un objeto que a su ves el objeto padre es una propiedades de un objeto aun mayor, y ya tengo el modelo de datos pero especificamente esta propiedad SubItems me arroja un error

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'AgenteWolop.Models.SubItems' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.